# Pause and Continue files with Fine Uploader

Tags: c#, angularjs, fine-uploader

My configurations.
Angular :  1.6, Back end : C#, Fine Uploader 5.

my upload is working fine but the new requirement is to upload a whole folder with pause and continue functionality.

Initially when folder is dropped, It should be in Pause state, and there must be a upload button for continue.

I have tried to complete it with `autoUpload: false` but it's also not working.

when I tries to continue my upload, it says that `Ignoring continue for file ID 0 (om.jpg).  Not paused.`

My code:

```
angular.module("fineUploaderDirective", [])
.directive("fineUploader", function ($compile, $interpolate) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,

    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        var endpoint = attrs.uploadServer,
            notAvailablePlaceholderPath = attrs.notAvailablePlaceholder,
            waitingPlaceholderPath = attrs.waitingPlaceholder,
            acceptFiles = attrs.allowedMimes,
            sizeLimit = attrs.maxFileSize,
            largePreviewSize = parseInt(attrs.largePreviewSize),
            allowedExtensions = JSON.parse(attrs.allowedExtensions),
            previewDialog = document.querySelector('.large-preview'),

            uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                debug: true,
                element: element[0],
                request: { endpoint: endpoint },

                validation: {
                    acceptFiles: acceptFiles,
                    allowedExtensions: allowedExtensions,
                    sizeLimit: sizeLimit
                },

                deleteFile: {
                    endpoint: endpoint,
                    enabled: true
                },

                thumbnails: {
                    placeholders: {
                        notAvailablePath: notAvailablePlaceholderPath,
                        waitingPath: waitingPlaceholderPath
                    }
                },

                display: {
                    prependFiles: true
                },

                failedUploadTextDisplay: {
                    mode: "custom"
                },

                retry: {
                    enableAuto: true
                },

                chunking: {
                    enabled: true
                },

                resume: {
                    enabled: true
                },

                callbacks: {
                    //onSubmit: function (id, name) {
                    //    debugger
                    //    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    //        debugger
                    //        // popup modal
                    //        // when user responds...
                    //        // ...call resolve() if they want to upload the file
                    //        // ...or reject() if they want to cancel the file

                    //        resolve()
                    //    });
                    //},
                    onSubmitted: function (id, name) {
                        var fileEl = this.getItemByFileId(id),
                            thumbnailEl = fileEl.querySelector('.thumbnail-button');

                        //thumbnailEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        //    openLargerPreview($scope, uploader, previewDialog, largePreviewSize, id);
                        //});
                    },
                    onSubmitDelete: function (id) {
                        this.setDeleteFileParams({ filename: this.getName(id) }, id)
                    },
                    onResume: function (id) {
                        alert(1)
                    }
                }
            });

        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(previewDialog);
        $scope.closePreview = closePreview.bind(this, previewDialog);
        bindToRenderedTemplate($compile, $scope, $interpolate, element);
    }
}
});
```

see below snap..
[image]

So, How can I pause all my dropped file Initially and then resume back when user commands.

Thanks in advance.